# asp.net mvc 3 razor get one element from IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I my view model(LIST) looks like this:

```
public class ConversationModel 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
        public string ToUserID{ get; set; }
    }
```

this is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<NGGmvc.Models.ConversationModel>
```

how i can get ToUserID on current postion? something like this

@Model[0].ToUserID

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
@Model.First().ToUserID
```

Note, you may want to check whether there are any items in the enumerable first as if there aren't, then First() will return null

(Note, because you had @Model[0] in your question, I assume you are specifically trying to get the first value. I may have the wrong end of the stick, in which case Jakub's answer should sort you out!)

Comment: AdTheDev, where do I gain MVC Model Jedi Knowledge.  Your answer resolved my issue.  On to the next problem.

Comment: Note that `@Model.First()` will throw an exception if the data is not found. Another option is to use `@Model.FirstOrDefault()` which will return null if data is not found, if there was a chance that the data wouldn't exist for example.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the following:

```
@Model.First().ToUserID
```

However, if your model will only ever reference the first element of the enumeration in the view, I would  recommend that you only pass that element to the view.

For example:

```
@model ConversationModel

@Model.ToUserID
```

And in the controller only pass the first element that is required:

```
List<ConversationModel> conversationList = //your conversation model initialisation code
return View(conversationList.First());
```

Comment: I've just seen the other answers and from this I am now questioning what it is you ask for?  Is it the first element of the enumerable type that you require or every element?

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach(var model in Model)
{
    @model.ToUserID
}
```