# How can I dynamically generate HTML attribute value with model.id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The button names should be added dynamically. 
A user suggested the solution below (`name="@model.id"`) but the syntax doesn't seem right.

How can I rewrite that HTML attribute (and add the static text "Button" to it)?

[image: **Index.cshtml**]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using the wrong keyword.

`model` is for setting model type

you should be using

```
@Model.id
```

P.S. case sensitive

Comment: I just realized the model was a IEnumerable<> (@model IEnumerable<UOL.Models.P_Followup>). How can I find a solution because I can't get the ID of each element?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598393/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-get-one-element-from-ienumerable.
Thank you for your help.